# multiple command button in a form not working as expected in Primefaces DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a DataTable, each row is provided with a `commandButton` to download a specific file.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{studentClassroomBean.papers}" var="paper" id="paperDT"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             paginator="true" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
             rowKey="#{paper.paperId}" style="margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;"
             selection="#{studentClassroomBean.selectedPapers}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width: 16px; text-align:center;"/>

    <p:column headerText="Download" style="text-align: center; width: 80px">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-download" actionListener="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadPaper}" 
                             ajax="false">
                <f:param name="paperId" value="#{paper.paperId}"/>
                <p:fileDownload value="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadFile}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Download Papers" icon="fa fa-download" ajax="false"
                         actionListener="#{studentClassroomBean.batchDownload}" process="paperDT">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadZip}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

This works perfectly if I only wrap `commandButton` with form instead of wrap the entire `dataTable`. The problem if I wrap the entire `dataTable` with form is the value of `<f:param name="paperId" value="#{paper.paperId}"/>` in managedBean will always be the same no matter which button you click on, like it doesn't update the value in managed bean after the first time download button was clicked. This is my `downloadPaper` function in ManagedBean

```
public void downloadPaper() throws IOException
{
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    Paper selectedPaper = paperService.findByPaperId(params.get("paperId"));
    String fullPath = DIRECTORY + selectedPaper.getFileName();
    String contentType = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getMimeType(fullPath);
    String fileName = selectedPaper.getTitle() + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fullPath);
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
    downloadFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, contentType, fileName);
}
```

This issue lead to the paper that user wish to download will always be the same paper as the first paper that he/she download. For example, I click on the download button of the first row, after that I click on download button of the second row, but the file downloaded will still be the same as the previous one, always. Can I know why? how to solve this? I have to wrap the whole dataTable with form in order to make `selection` works. Any idea on how to solve this conflict? Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue solved by using another method to pass the parameter to bean.
Instead of pass the parameter by using `<f:param>` tag

```
<p:column headerText="Download" style="text-align: center; width: 80px">
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-download" actionListener="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadPaper}" 
             ajax="false">
        <f:param name="paperId" value="#{paper.paperId}"/>
        <p:fileDownload value="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadFile}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<p:column headerText="Download" style="text-align: center; width: 80px">
    <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-download" actionListener="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadPaper(paper.paperId)}" 
                     ajax="false">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{studentClassroomBean.downloadFile}"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

and catch the parameter at managed bean like this:

```
public void downloadPaper(String paperId) throws IOException
{
    Paper selectedPaper = paperService.findByPaperId(paperId);
    String fullPath = DIRECTORY + selectedPaper.getFileName();
    String contentType = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getMimeType(fullPath);
    String fileName = selectedPaper.getTitle() + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(fullPath);
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
    downloadFile = new DefaultStreamedContent(input, contentType, fileName);
}
```

Not sure where is the trick but it works. Hope it helps some people out there